# Convert Hyperlink in Google Sheets to URL using VBA

Tags: vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of hyperlinked text. The anchor text are words that are hyperlinked.

I want to take the links underneath the text and either replace the text with the raw url or add the urls to another column.

I've managed to find a tutorial that does this perfectly in MS Excel using a macro, but I can't seem to find a way to do this in Google Sheets as my working computer does not have MS Excel. The only things I can find for Google Sheets is a way to extract the url from cells using the `Hyperlink()` function, which I am not using.

Is there a way to translate this macro into a GAS script for Google Sheets or any other way to grab the urls from hyperlinks?

MACRO/VBA/Excel:

```vb
Sub removeHyperlinks()
Dim Cell As Range 
For Each Cell In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange) 
    If Cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then 
        Cell.Value = Cell.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address 
    End If 
Next
End Sub
```

source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=012u3YVo9pw

**EDIT:** In trying to translate this into from VBA to GAS I am encountering `Cell.Hyperlinks.Count.` There doesn't seem to be a GAS equivalent for `Hyperlinks`

Comment: Yes there will be but this isn't a code writing service. This will need to be re-written in Apps-Script language. Do some research and give it a try.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for? :https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ymxKs_QVEbs

Comment: Btw not sure what you mean by?: "The only thins I can find for Google Sheets is a way to extract the url from cells using the Hyperlink() function, which I am not using." you are not using hyperlink function to setup hyperlinks in google sheet? Then how are you setting up the hyperlink

Comment: Hi, I have copied the list from a website and pasted it into the spreadsheet, so the sheet is not creating the links. The example you shared uses the hyperlink() formula.

Comment: Can you share an example sheet? to give it a try?